# Adding Elements Of Two Linked List To Form Third Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I need a little help with my new assignment.
Problem:

> Given Two Linked List representation of a decimal numbers(238 & 35):-
>  2->3->8 and,
>  3->5
>
> **Add elements** so that your Final Linked List must be   2->7->3.

What could be the best approach to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you get `2->7->3` from those 2 lists?

Comment: Consider two integers taking values from two list.<br/> integer1=238 & integer2:35. Now add them , you got: 273. Now represent them as a linked list such that each node has only one digit.Thus,2->7->3.

Comment: This is a homework problem that reappears every semester. EVery time, the students fail to mention that the linked list of numbers represent decimal digits of a multi-digit number, and the assignment is to add them as decimal numbers.

Comment: how can final be `2->7->3` and what have you tried? Please let us know where you are facing problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without doing your homework for you - I think the best general approach would be to break it into three steps.

1. Reverse both the lists.
2. Add the elements pairwise, carrying a one where necessary.
3. Reverse the resulting list.

Since step 1 and step 3 are kind of the same, you probably want to write a separate function for this.

Give it a try, and post again if you need more help.